# Creating a drag and drop GUI for multiphysics simulation software

Tags: user-interface, simulation

I have spend a reasonable part of my career writing engineering simulation software but as these pieces of code have only been used internally I have never written an interface and have no experience of GUIs at all. I am now thinking of making my software more user friendly and would like to make a drag and drop interface where components a can be dragged from a menu of some sort, probably something like a tree and dropped onto a palette and linked up into a system. An example of a commercial interface might be modelica, simcape or GT suite for example. I'd be grateful for any advice about what the easiest language to use would be, or any recommendations for books or tutorials to get me started please?

I haven't coded anything yet as I'm not sure where to start but I am going to write some simple dragging and dropping of images in VB.NET as that is the language I am most familiar with.

Comment: Hi. For starters you MAY read the articles here: https://www.nngroup.com .
Especially https://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-101-introduction-to-usability/ .

Comment: A goo e-book on the Modelica language which incorporate GUI in the language definition is https://mbe.modelica.university